# For loop in twig with js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twig

I need little bit help in for loop.

i have one array under which there are 25 items.When i am rendering on page then through for loop 1st 10 items i am showing and the remaining 15 items on scroll i am showing through ajax call. In 1st ajax call i am showing 10 items and the rest 5 items are showing in 2nd ajax call.In this ajax call i am sending product id so that i can get product from database.

Note:- If i have 100 items, I send 10 ajax call.

What i want is the ajax call i am sending ,in that 1st ajax call i send 10 items id and the remaining 5 items id i send in 2nd ajax call.

Right now My code send 15 items ids in both ajax call.

Here is code :-

```
    var prodId = new Array();
    {% for pd in entities %}
       {% if loop.index <= 10 %}
          prodId.push('{{ pd.id }}');
       {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    $(document).ready(function(){
    var count=25;//This is dynamic

    if (count>10) {
        count=count-10;
    }

    $(window).scroll(function(){
            var scrollH = $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height();
            var documentH = $(document).height();
            var infty_scrl_end=$('#sectiontop').offset().top;   
            if (count>0) {
            console.log(prodId);
                if(scrollH > infty_scrl_end){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "url_ajax",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: { "data" : prodId },
                        success: function(data) {
                            $(data).appendTo('.container');
                        }
                    }); 
                    count=count-10;
                }
            }


    });
    });
```

Thanks !

Comment: what is the output of console.log(prodId) ;

Comment: @LogicBlower Thanks for comment. console.log(prodId) print items ids like :-  [0] => 4    [1] => 9  [2] => 10 [3] => 22 [4] => 17 etc..

Comment: So , i guess prodid is the Array which contains 15 items , that is being sent (data) over in ajax to server ? , if yes , then where is the logic for cutting id's (like sending only 5 id's from proid array to server) ? like if i on track you are sending proid id to server and want the result of that id's  .  hope what i am trying to say make sens

Answer (score 0):

You could work with a queue to solve this,

```
var prodId = new Array();
{% for pd in entities %}
    prodId.push('{{ pd.id }}'); //Fill up the total queue
{% endfor %}

$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollH = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        var documentH = $(document).height();
        var infty_scrl_end = $('#sectiontop').offset().top;

        if (scrollH > infty_scrl_end){
            loadQueue();
        }
    });

    loadQueue();
});


function loadQueue() {
    if (prodId.length == 0) return;

    //split the queue in parts of 10
    var tmp = new Array();    
    while(tmp.length < 10 && prodId.length > 0) {
        tmp.push(prodId.shift());
    }
    if (tmp.length == 0) return;

    $.ajax({
        url: "url_ajax",
        type: "POST",
        data: { "data" : prodId },
        success: function(data) {
            $(data).appendTo('.container');
        }
    }); 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for support. This code make 3 ajax call but this is also sending all remaining 15 id's in first ajax call. I want if 25 items then 10 items I already showed without ajax and remaining 15 id's I want to show through 2 ajax call when user scroll.

Comment: What do you mean all 15 remaining? This code just send your product id's with chunks of 10 and fetches them

Comment: This code send all ids in first ajax and second ajax call so third ajax call is empty and send same ids in 1st and 2nd ajax call......All 15 remaining means if I have 25 items then 10 items I have already showed without ajax call and remaining 15 I want to show via ajax call...so remaining 15 items make 2 ajax call first ajax call with 10 items and second ajax call with 5 items.

Comment: This code sends 10 items in first call, 10 in the second call and 5 in the last call actually.

Comment: No In you code on 1st ajax call sending 15 Id's and second ajax call sending 5 it's and 3rd ajax call no id's.

Comment: Not really. Use debug tools and check javascript console for the logging https://jsfiddle.net/oka16zxp/3/